# Adjust Table | Landscape Page | Adjust Text

Tags: tables, longtable, text

I have been making an assignment for for the qualification on the course for my wife, in landscape form using long table. It is turning to be larger than the page. *I'm inexperienced in matters of LaTeX*.

1. **As well as to adjust the table in page?**
2. **The is large text area!! Like going to try adjusting the text, someone know how to make?**

*I thank you in advance*.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}      
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage{mathpazo}           

%\usepackage{indentfirst}               

\setlength{\parskip}{2mm}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.554cm,bottom=2.554cm,left=2.554cm,right=2.554cm]{geometry} 

\usepackage{a4wide}             

\usepackage{setspace}           


\usepackage{color}              
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor=black,
            urlcolor=blue,
            citecolor=black]{hyperref}

%\usepackage{hyperref}          

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{textcomp}           

\usepackage{siunitx}     
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{array}              
\usepackage{booktabs}           
\usepackage{tabularx}           
\usepackage{longtable}          
\usepackage{lscape}             

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./imagens/}}

% \usepackage{helvet}
% \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}       


%\linespread{1.3}

%\usepackage[round,sort,nonamebreak]{natbib} % 
%\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}

\usepackage[square, comma, authoryear, sort&compress, nonamebreak]{natbib}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

==================================================================================================================================================

\newpage
\begin{landscape}

\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{longtable}{c|c|c|c|>{\arraybackslash}p{6.5cm}@{}}
\hline
Desenho do Estudo & Principais Resultados & Ano  & Referência \\ \hline

Caracterização física de frutos e sementes de goiaba-da-costa-rica, produzidos em Manaus-Amazonas & O fruto apresentou atributos favoráveis ao aproveitamento industrial, como o elevado rendimento em polpa (94$\%$) O número elevado de sementes por fruto representa uma característica facilitadora à propagação e produção de mudas. &     85,00    & 80,80    \\

Manganês            & mg    &   0,09     &  0,15    \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\caption{Estudos Sobre Aplicação dos Resíduos da Goiaba.}
\label{cqsg}
\end{table}

\end{landscape}
\newpage
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!  Please make your example compilable with an minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem.

Comment: BTW: `longtable` in `table` makes not sense. `table` is a float but `longtable` should have page breaks that cannot be in floats. You should use either `tabular` in `table` or `longtable` without `table`. And you have declared 5 columns but using only 4. Maybe you should either use 4 `p`-columns or 4 `c`-columns and `\multicolumn` with `p`-columns for the long texts inside the columns.

Comment: Can you help me?

With a sample code!

I need the text to fit in the first two columns. Long texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ltxtable` package, which brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`. I also loaded `caption` to adjust the caption width and have a decent vertical spacing between caption and table. Needless in this case to load `longtable, tabularx` and `array` in this case.

It's better to use the `utf8`  inputenc, as it is the default in most modern TeX editors, and to declare default language with the document class, so that all packages depending on the language be aware of it

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, brazil]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\setlength{\parskip}{2mm}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.554cm,bottom=2.554cm,left=2.554cm,right=2.554cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{bigstrut} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[square, comma, authoryear, sort&compress, nonamebreak]{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor=black,
            urlcolor=blue,
            citecolor=black]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\centering\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\keepXColumns\captionsetup{width=\linewidth}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|c|c|}%>{\arraybackslash}p{6.5cm}@{}}
\caption{Estudos Sobre Aplicação dos Resíduos da Goiaba.}
\label{cqsg}\\
\hline
\endfirsthead%
 \hline \endfoot
Desenho do Estudo & Principais Resultados & Ano & Referência \\ \hline

Caracterização física de frutos e sementes de goiaba-da-costa-rica, produzidos em Manaus-Amazonas & O fruto apresentou atributos favoráveis ao aproveitamento industrial, como o elevado rendimento em polpa (94$\%$) O número elevado de sementes por fruto representa uma característica facilitadora à propagação e produção de mudas. & 85,00 & 80,80 \\
Manganês & mg & 0,09 & 0,15 \bigstrut[t]
\end{tabularx}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]